# sass sum or rest depending the argument in a function

Tags: variables, sass

I am refactoring functions in my sass code so their use is broader while trying to follow as much as possible functional programming rules. How can I assign the type of operation depending on parameter so I don't have to repeat code inside if else statements?

In fact what I want to achieve is to select next or previous index on a list

```
@function mathOperation($number, $type) {
    @return $number #{if($type == sum, '+', '-')} 1;
}

@debug mathOperation(5, sum);
@debug type-of(mathOperation(5, sum));
```

Gives as result

```
DEBUG 5 + 1 
DEBUG list
```

Instead of the actual sum and type number.

Even tried to directly pass the actual operator such as + or - as argument and simply use it as variable, with no luck.

Comment: If you want to select items from a list use a map instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a sass list in your function rather than you do a mathematical calculation. Using *inspect()*, you could create a string from ist so what you basically are searching for is a method to eval a string. 
Sass does not offer this, you will have to write a numerical equation that returns a number like

```
@function mathOperation($number, $type) {
    @return $number + if($type == sum, 1, -1);
}
```